# Getting the object's propertys container/father

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

i have this issue where i can get the data from my express server and put them in variables and then put/display them inside a div.
My problem is if the object property "important" is off the father/div container should be display: none.
Here is an console.log example:

```
function filterImportant(){
    const fetchFile = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api"); // first connect to api
        const data = await res.json(); // is a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using the JSON.stringify() method.
        data.notes.forEach((note)=>{
            if(note.important !== "on"){
                console.log(note);
            }
        });
    }
    fetchFile();
}
```

[image]

However if i console.log(note.parentNode), it logs undefined.
I need to get the father/conteiner of these objects, if thats possible.
Thank you in advance.

Edit, since i didn't hava space in the comments.
Express, sends this file(NoteDb.json) as the variable "data", in the endpoint /api. I fetch it from the endpoint. This is the data express sends:

```
{"notes":[{"noteName":"test1","important":"on","reminder":"2021-09-22","noteMsg":"test1","creationDate":"11/9/2021"},{"noteName":"important1","important":"on","reminder":"2021-09-22","noteMsg":"important1","creationDate":"11/9/2021"},{"noteName":"important2","important":"on","reminder":"2021-09-21","noteMsg":"important2","creationDate":"11/9/2021"},{"noteName":"notImportant1","important":"off","reminder":"2021-09-14","noteMsg":"notImportant1","creationDate":"11/9/2021"},{"noteName":"notImportant2","important":"off","reminder":"2021-09-28","noteMsg":"notImportant2","creationDate":"11/9/2021"},{"noteName":"notImportant3","important":"off","reminder":"2021-09-29","noteMsg":"notImportant3","creationDate":"12/9/2021"}]}
```

Someone asked me to show i rendered the divs, here it is:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        //--------------------------------------
        const fetchFile = async () => {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api"); // first connect to api
            const data = await res.json(); // is a response (with the correct content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using the JSON.stringify() method.
            const noteDisplay = document.getElementById('noteDisplay');
            //-------------------------------
            if(data.notes.length < 1){
                let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
                paragraph.setAttribute("id", "msg");
                let innerMsg = document.createTextNode("There aren't any notes!");
                paragraph.appendChild(innerMsg);
                //-----------------------
                noteDisplay.append(paragraph);
                //console.log(paragraph);
            } else {
                noteDisplay.style.display = "block";
                data.notes.forEach((note)=>{
        /*note*/    let div = document.createElement("div"); // creation of the note
                    div.setAttribute("class", "note"); // giving them class "note"
                    //---------------------
   /*note-header*/  let header = document.createElement("div"); // created the header
                    header.setAttribute("class", "header"); // then gave it the "header" class
                    div.appendChild(header); // and then append the header to the "note"

                    let spanHeader = document.createElement("span"); // lets create a span to hold the noteName
                    let noteName = document.createTextNode(note.noteName); // then we get the object key/value pair
                    spanHeader.appendChild(noteName); // then we append to the span the noteName
                    header.appendChild(spanHeader); // and to the header the span
                    //---------------------
   /*note-body*/    let body = document.createElement("div");
                    body.setAttribute("class", "body");
                    div.appendChild(body);

                    let spanBody = document.createElement("span");
                    let noteMsg = document.createTextNode(note.noteMsg);
                    spanBody.appendChild(noteMsg);
                    body.appendChild(spanBody);
                    //---------------------
                    noteDisplay.append(div); // then adding them to the "note display"
                    //console.log(note.noteName);
                    //---------------------
   /*note-footer*/  let footer = document.createElement("div");
                    footer.setAttribute("class", "footer");
                    div.appendChild(footer);

                    let spanFooter = document.createElement("span");
                    let noteCreationDate = document.createTextNode(`Creation date: ${note.creationDate}`);
                    spanFooter.appendChild(noteCreationDate);
                    footer.appendChild(spanFooter);
                });
            }
        }
        fetchFile();
    });
```

*These are different files thats why the function names are the same, one is for rendering the divs an the other is for filtering.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the `data` object looks like? It's a bit hard to tell what you are trying to achieve. It looks like the `note` objects do not have a `parentNode` attribute.

Comment: @nullromo, i edited my questions since i didn't have space here, hope i answered your question.

Comment: Can you also show how are you rendering the divs?

Comment: @HarshitRastogi, i've added thediv rendering, hope it helps.

Comment: You can filter out `data.notes` where `important: "off"`. If the length of filtered array is greater than one then you can apply the style to the parent node

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is only create the `div`s for notes that have `important: 'on'`. If that's the case, then just add some conditional logic like `if(note.important === 'off') {...} else {...}`.

Comment: @HarshitRastogi, sorry for being a noob, but i did not understand your answer. Reason being is that i cannot relate one another. Like in my code i have to use "if(note.important !== "on")", lets say that i get 3 that are "off", how do i relete them to their div container. Cause like i said "note.parentNode.style.display"/"note.parent.style.display", gives me an error. Even if i log(note.parentNode)/log.(note.parent), it give me 3x undefined.

Comment: @nullromo, more like, they are already created independently of on or off. Now when i want to filter them, is when i only want the ones that have "on". And yes i already have that system/method implemented, in the first picture .

Comment: It's confusing because in the code you provided, you create the `div`s regardless of the `important` property. You can't access the parent node of an HTML tree via a JSON object that is unrelated to the tree. That JSON has no connection to the DOM. It's just JSON data about your notes. When you then go to render the page, you can choose what to render based on the data. So you would normally render one note `div` per item in the JSON data response (except you could then leave out some if they are `important: 'off'`. I think you need to provide more context to get a better answer.

Comment: @nullromo, Aleluia, i got it. But yes i feel what you are saying. I guess what i really wanted was to know if there was any relation with my div and the object inside of it. As to the solution, i rethink my code, and in the div creation i added a function, that "if note.important === "off"", i added the class to the div, thus me being able to filter it now. Thanks alot!